# how to convert input field value to base64 encode or decode in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

how to convert input field value to base64 encode or decode in angular js if any body know plz answered

I Want to convert input field value to base64

Answer (score 2):

Use the `btoa()` function to encode:

```
console.log(btoa("test"));
```

To decode, you can use the `atob()` function:

```
console.log(atob("dGVzdA=="))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: it's work on console

but how to use with input field

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mymodel" class="form-controle" id="myid" />
var string = $('#myid').val();
var encodedString = btoa(string);
console.log(encodedString);
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString);
```

Comment: Not Work Deepak Bro